# how to confirm quit application in fragment ? when user press back key

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, keyevent

i am creating an applicaiton with different fragments. I want to add code to listener for  back key event and confirm with user if he wants to exit the app or not..

```
public class FastivalesFragment extends Fragment {

public FastivalesFragment(){

    }
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    List<EventClass> tempRows = new ArrayList<EventClass>();
    EditText searchTxt;


    ListView list;
    View view;
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Log.d("LifeCycle now is", "onCreateView");



        // searchTxt = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


         tempRows.clear(); // to delete all objects form temp array

          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list, container, false);

          list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          int j=0;
          while (AllEventsFragment.rowItems.size() > j){

              Log.d(" the value for region ", "is "+ AllEventsFragment.rowItems.get(j).getCategory());

              if (AllEventsFragment.rowItems.get(j).getCategory().equals("أخرى")) {
                  tempRows.add(AllEventsFragment.rowItems.get(j));
              }

              j++;
          }
              adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.item_view,tempRows);
              list.setAdapter(adapter);



            //list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        //Log.e("value of name ", " "+ arg2);

                        String name = tempRows.get(arg2).getName();
                        String details = tempRows.get(arg2).getDetails();

                        String ticketPrice = tempRows.get(arg2).getTicketPrice();
                        String boolingUrl = tempRows.get(arg2).getBookingUrl();



                      Log.e("sdate", " "+ sdate);


                        Intent i = new Intent (getActivity(), Event_details.class);
                        i.putExtra("name", name);
                        i.putExtra("details", details);
                        i.putExtra("sdate", sdate);
                        i.putExtra("edate", edate);
                        i.putExtra("time", time);

                        i.putExtra("boolingUrl", boolingUrl);




                        startActivity(i);




                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Log.e("position"," "+ arg2);

                    }
                });




         return view;

        }




    //onCreate method
     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


         Log.d("LifeCycle now is", "onCreate");
     } // end of Attach

    //onPause() method
         @Override
         public void onPause(){
             super.onPause();
                //rowItems.clear(); // to delete all objects form temp array

             Log.d("LifeCycle now is", "onPause()");
         } // end of onPause
    //onResume() method
         @Override
         public void onResume(){
             super.onResume();

             Log.d("LifeCycle now is", "onResume()");
         } // end of onResume      



}
```

I used the following code for activity and it works fine.. but it does not work the fragment file above.

```
    // confirm when user click back key
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //Yes button clicked
               finish();
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
     .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
     .setCancelable(false)
     .setTitle("Exit");
     builder.show();

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

when i copy this code the above fragment .. i got error of : The method onKeyDown is undefiled for type  Fragment..

Comment: You can add an onBackPressed listener to your Activity and check against your Fragment stack to see if you need to create a dialog to remove the Fragment from the Activity.

Comment: "I want to add code to listener for back key event and confirm with user if he wants to exit the app or not" -- that is inappropriate. Bear in mind that the user can "exit the app" in any number of ways: BACK, HOME, accepting an incoming phone call, responding to a `Notification`, etc. Whatever concern you have over the user exiting via BACK also needs to be addressed for those other scenarios, where you cannot "confirm with user". You need to handle all of these scenarios *automatically*.

Comment: at least I want to handle back key because normally users does not mean to close the app. How can I do that ? can you help me to find sample code for who do  onBackPressed listener  ? where I should put this code in main activity or in each fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the above code in the Main Activity not in each Fragment.  Thanks Alls