# How can I confirm exit from the individual fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been able to confirm exit before leaving fragment. However my activity has six cards each of which calls a fragment when clicked. The confirm exit applies to all fragments in this activity. How can I apply to individual fragment say to the Garden Mapping card which calls its own fragment(It is called GpsFragment). I need to confirm exit before leaving this Fragment(GpsFragment)

This is my main menu

[image]

This is my code  in the main activity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 1) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Closing EzyAgric")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close EzyAgric?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850104/how-to-confirm-quit-application-in-fragment-when-user-press-back-key

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface to comunicate with your activity and fragment

```
public abstract class BackPressFragment extends BaseFragment {
    public abstract boolean processBackPress();
}

YourFragment extends BackPressFragment {
    .....
}
```

And process key event in your activity, pass event through the interface.

Comment: is it an answer?  or comment?

Comment: I mean you can define an interface and pass your activity back press key event to your fragment, and process the event.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to send the onBackPressed() event to the fragment. Best way to do that is via an interface.
Create an Interface like this:

```
 public interface IOnBackPressListener {

     void onBackPressed();
  }
```

Now implement your interface in the fragment like this:

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressListener {

    public MyFragment(){

   }

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     Log.e("Fragment","On Back pressed");
       // Alert code comes here
     }
    }
```

Now in your activity write the following code in onBackPressed()

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     IOnBackPressListener fragment=((IOnBackPressListener) 
     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));
     if(fragment!=null)
        fragment.onBackPressed();
     }
```

Comment: I am trying out this. Kindly explain the code in the activity

Comment: In the activity you get the current fragment from fragment manager. Then you will send the call back to that particular fragment

Comment: Ok , and about the R.id.container

Comment: R.id.container is the parent layout that holds the fragment. In my case I have used FrameLayout. If you have used <Fragment> then give its id.

Comment: let me try with FrameLayout and see. Because for me I was using RelativeLayout